# Doc file writer not working

Tags: java, android

I am using this method to write something in doc file. But the file is not opening after creating file.Its not opening in the phone.Please help me out.I'm new in android

```
 public void wr(View v){
     String sFileName="GradeSheet.docx";
       String sBody=note;
       try
        { 
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "NSUGT");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved in SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();

        }


 }
```

Comment: is `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the manifest file?

Comment: is there any logcat message?

Comment: pulled question before code

Comment: manifest is alright no logcat message.